# Rebuilding WAR files in webapps directory

Tags: haskell, file-system, comparative-review, shell

This script cleans up destination directory and copies file into it with new name. Can this intent be expressed more cleanly with `shelly`?

```
main = shellyFailDir $ verbosely $ do
  escaping False $ rm_rf $ webapps </> "*"
  cp (m2repo
       </> groupPath
       </> artifact
       </> version
       </> (intercalate "-" [artifact, version] `append` ".war")
     ) $ webapps </> (finalName `append` ".war")
  echo "done"
```

Alternate take:

```
main = shellyFailDir $ verbosely $ do
  ls webapps >>= mapM_ rm_rf
  cp (m2repo <> groupPath <> (mconcat . map fromText $ [artifact, version, artifactFileName]))
     $ webapps <> fromText (finalName <> extension)
  echo "done"

artifactFileName = intercalate "-" [artifact, version] <> extension
```

Having (types match only second version because they help pick correct `Monoid`):

```
m2repo = ".m2/repository" :: FilePath
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT" :: Text
webapps = "tomcat/webapps" :: FilePath
groupPath = "com/example" :: FilePath
artifact = "app" :: Text
finalName = artifact
extension = ".war" :: Text
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your first version looks pretty slick. You could use a let-binding to do a little reordering and naming.

```
import Data.Monoid

main = shellyFailDir $ verbosely $ do
  escaping False $ rm_rf $ webapps </> "*"
  let sourceName = artifact <> "-" <> version <> ".war"
      source = m2repo </> groupPath </> artifact </> version </> sourceName
      destination = webapps </> finalName <> ".war"
  cp source destination
  echo "done"
```